# Chromium developer tools - save resource from page

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an app that generates different json responses (both name and content) whenever a specific URL is hit. As an example, here's a sample app that generates a random json opened in Chrome developer tools:

[image]

These are the options I see:

- I can do right-click and then "Open Link in New Tab", however (not surprisingly) goes and fetches the URL again and I'm not getting the original json. Troubleshooting is thus not possible, as the new document doesn't have the right data.
- I can also pick "Save as HAR with Content", however that saves all resources all with the metadata, so kind of defeats the purpose when troubleshooting.
- What I'm doing right now - copy-paste into an editor. This seems to be working fine, however I lose the resource name. Being an UUID (instead of sample.json, the name is something like `data-37328b29-3865-460f-9c28-8f0a3b5f2c17.json`), not fun making sure I got the right and the right content every time (or maybe that last Ctrl+C did not work...)

Is there a way to save the response as-is into a file, preferably with the resource name?